# How to make this cast implicit?

Tags: c++

I have

```
  class Wrapper : Base
{
Wrapper(WrappedObject& obj)
//...
};

void fun(Base& b);
```

I want to be able to directly call `fun` with a `WrappedObject` instance, is such an implicit conversion possible? how?

edit :
http://ideone.com/ilfE8 i still can't make this example to work, what do I need to change?
thanks

Answer (score 6):

Make the inheritance public:

```
class Wrapper : public Base
```

As it is, that isn't an `is-a` relationship. `private` inheritance (which is default for classes) represents a `has-a` relationship.

```
class Wrapper : Base
```

is equivalent to

```
class Wrapper : private Base
```

EDIT: As per the comments, the reference has to be const because a temporary will be created.

Comment: I'll check thanks, I can't believe I forgot the keyword... it's a mistake on my part then

Comment: That won't work because `fun` takes its parameter by non-const reference.

Comment: @MarkB so? Unless he's passing a temporary, it shouldn't matter. Maybe `fun` modifies the parameter.

Comment: The OP wants to pass a `WrappedObject`, NOT a `Wrapper`, and have the `WrappedObject` implicitly create a child class temporary to pass into `fun`, unless I misread the question.

Comment: @MarkB aaaa I missed that part. Sorry. I thought the cast was 1-level, but in this case a temp has to be created, so the reference has to be const. You're right.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this in one step if `fun` really needs to take its parameter by non-const reference. The reason is that in order to call `fun` you need create a temporary `Wrapper` from a `WrappedObject`, but this temporary can't then be bound to a non-const reference.

If `fun` can take its parameter as const reference then you just need to change the inheritance to `public` as seen in the other answer, and make `fun`'s parameter const. Then you can do exactly what you asked for.

If `fun` must take its parameter by non-const reference you'll *have* to create a named temporary object to pass into it:

```
Wrapper wrap(wrapped_obj);
fun(wrap);
```

Finally note that while implicit constructors are convenient they can often inhibit code comprehension and lead to hard-to-find bugs. Remember that you write code only once and spelling out conversions explicitly (rather than implicit converting constructors) will lead to easier-to-read code and make bugs stand out more obviously.

EDIT: Upon further inspection I don't believe your original goal can be achieved in C++. (Un)fortunately due to the rules, it's not able to use multiple implicit steps (construct temp `Wrapper`, implicit cast to `Base`) to call the function. You'll have to help it out.

Probably the simplest way is an overloaded `fun(const Wrapper& w) { fun(static_cast<const Base&>(w)); }` while the alternate method is to explicitly create a temporary `Wrapper` object in the call to `fun` itself, which does have the advantage of being slightly more explicit to future readers.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, however my really function takes a const reference, so a temporary is ok. I'm leaving the question as is for reference

Comment: class A {
   public:
    static double test_code(const A& a);
   };

   class B : public A {
public:
    B(int i) { };
   };

   A::test_code(2);

is this supposed to work? It's basically what I'm trying to do but this fails to compile because no conversion is found